# How to style th and td tag in data table additional-attributes

Tags: magento2, less, table, additional-information

I need to style the `th` and `td` tag in the 'additional-attributes' table (under the *More information* tab), with the css class: `data table additional-attributes`. See screenshot.

[image]

Where (which less file) do I find the styling for the `th` and `td` tag? I need to adjust the padding.

```
.product.info.detailed .additional-attributes > thead > tr > td,.product.info.detailed .additional-attributes > tbody > tr > td,.product.info.detailed .additional-attributes > tfoot > tr > td {
    padding: 4px 5px 10px 5px
}

.product.info.detailed .additional-attributes > thead > tr > th,.product.info.detailed .additional-attributes > tbody > tr > th,.product.info.detailed .additional-attributes > tfoot > tr > th {
    padding: 4px 30px 10px 0
}
```

Comment: You should be able to override anything using _extend.less, does that help?

Comment: Yes thats correct. I am using  `_extend.less`, but where I find the less file where the `th` and `td` tags are styled?

Comment: You would just make your own rule, open said file and put `body .product.info.detailed .additional-attributes > thead > tr > td,.product.info.detailed .additional-attributes > tbody > tr > td,body .product.info.detailed .additional-attributes > tfoot > tr > td { (your padding rule) }` and that should do it, once compiled. Edit: note I added `body` to make sure the rule overrides the magento default.